# Nuget fails to install specific version

Tags: nuget

I was able to set up my own NuGet server (as described [here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds)). 
The server `Packages` folder contains several versions of `MyPackage`, say 1.0.8.0 and 1.0.9.0.
When I install it in a default way (with no version specified), it gets installed successfully. But when I explicitly do

```
Install-Package MyPackage -Version 1.0.9.0
```

it goes wrong with the following message:

> Install-Package : **Unable to find version '1.0.9.0' of package 'MyPackage'**.
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + install-package <<<<  MyPackage -Version 1.0.9.0
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

**UPDATE:** 
This error message appears when `Package Source` in Package Manager Console is set to "ALL". When I set it to my own source (where, in fact, the package is expected to be found), another error appears:

```
Install-Package : **There are multiple root elements. Line 42, position 2.**
At line:1 char:16
+ install-package <<<<  dfct.shell.core.contracts -Version "1.0.8.0"
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], XmlException
+  FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Multiple root elements, Line 42? In what file?
Why is that? I think there's something wrong on the server side, but can't figure out what it is.

Comment: After the error occurs in the Package Manager Console try looking at the full stack trace for the exception using: `$error[0].exception.stacktrace`. That should point to where in NuGet the problem is occurring.

Answer (score 5):

Turned out that coexistence of both `MyPackage.1.0.9.0.nupkg`  and `MyPackage.1.0.9.0.symbols.nupkg` caused NuGet to crash. NuGet uses OData as transport and somewhere deep in OData it could not serialize/deserialize two packages, complaining about "multiple root nodes". 
So I simply removed `-symbols` from `nuget pack` command line thus disabling debug packages generation, and now it all works fine.

Comment: I had the same problem however the error message was different. The package install would fail with code 1. Removing the symbols packages from the same directory resolved the issue!

Comment: Also make sure there are no duplicates of the same library with a different name. In my case there was a loose "Copy of MyPackage.X.X.X.nupkg" file in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Got a similar error when trying to install `EntityFramework`.

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.1.3


Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' with respect to project 'Project.Data.Entities', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'
Gathering dependency information took 6,19 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3'
Resolved actions to install package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3'
Found package 'EntityFramework 6.1.3' in 'C:\dev\ProjectSource\packages'.
Package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' already exists in folder 'C:\dev\ProjectSource\packages'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' does not exist in project 'Project.Data.Entities'
Executing nuget actions took 695,25 ms
Install-Package : There are multiple root elements. Line 22, position 2.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.1.3
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Time Elapsed: 00:00:01.1494321
```

Turned out `App.config` had become corrupt, probably when upgrading `target framework`. There was now two `</configuration>` and `<startup>` was a new root element, therefore the error `multiple root elements`.

Corrupt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="RabbitMQ.Client" publicKeyToken="89e7d7c5feba84ce" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.6.9.0" newVersion="3.6.9.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/></startup></configuration>
```

Manually fixed version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="RabbitMQ.Client" publicKeyToken="89e7d7c5feba84ce" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.6.9.0" newVersion="3.6.9.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```